# Get full stack trace from remote session

Tags: session, powershell, powershell-3.0, invoke-command

I'm using Invoke-Expression under remote session and when throws exception - it returns just RemoteException without any stack trace information. 
Example:

```
try
{
    Invoke-Expression "$command 2>&1"
}    
catch
{
    Write-Host $_    
}
```

If I exclude redirect error to output(`2>&1`) - I'm getting proper error but it call unwanted debug console(from $command), which is hidden using redirection.

```
Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath $CmdExe -ArgumentList $Arguments
```

Using Start-Process I can see full stack trace but also have unwanted debug console.

How can I get a full stack trace and proper Exception from thrown exception under remote session?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a remote session, don't use write-host.  Try this:

```
catch { 
    Write-Error ($_ | fl * -force | out-string)
}
```

The other option is not to catch the exception and the let error propagate back to the local session.  But I suspect you want to attempt to recover?

Comment: Thanks Keith, no I don't want to recover, I just need to get an error to define true reason. In your example I see full information about remote exception and nothing about the real exception(should be info that xml structure is broken)

Comment: Try changing the `fl` to `fc` (Format-Custom).  That will follow nested objects (like Exception.InnerException) down something like four levels.